# maximum order of elements $s_i \in S_i$

Tags: group-theory

Give for every Permutation group $S_i, i = 4,5,6,7$ an element $s_i \in S_i$ with maximum order.

$s_4:=(1~2~3~4)\in S_4, ~ord(s_4)=4$

$s_5:=(1~2)(3~4~5)\in S_5, ~ord(s_5)=6$

$s_6:=(1~2~3~4~5~6)\in S_6, ~ord(s_6)=6$

$s_7:=(1~2~3)(4~5~6~7)\in S_7, ~ord(s_7)=12$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: It's OK apart from a typo (and it has nothing at all to do with linear algebra).

Comment: Why is $ord(s_{5})=10$. I'm just curious...

Comment: Sorry, i've corrected it

Answer (score 0):

You can check your solution against Sloane's OEIS A000793.
Table[Max[Map[Apply[LCM, #] &, Partitions[n]]], {n, 1, 20}]